# JavaFX interface not showing properly when exported as JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, executable-jar

[Here is a picture of my interface when running the project in Eclipse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx7c4.png)

[And this is the interface when  ran after the project is exported to a jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MUSo.png)

Controller:

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button kBtn;
    @FXML
    private Button bpBtn;
    @FXML
    private Button genButton;

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    public static File kasasaFile;
    public static File billPayFile;

    public void handleKButton(ActionEvent event) {
        fc.setTitle("Select Kasasa File");
        kasasaFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    }

    public void handleBPButton(ActionEvent event) {
        fc.setTitle("Select Bill Pay File");
        billPayFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);



    }

    public void handleGenerateButton(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException {

    }
    }
```

FXML file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="336.0" prefWidth="422.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.151" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="180.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse..." onAction="#handleKButton" />
      <Button layoutX="180.0" layoutY="125.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse..." onAction="#handleBPButton"/>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="64.0" text="Choose Kasasa accounts file" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="128.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Choose bill pay accounts file" />
      <Button layoutX="131.0" layoutY="244.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Generate refund document" onAction="#handleGenerateButton"/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main:

```
package application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
        launch(args);

        Set<String> rewardsAccountsList = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> billPayAccountsList = new HashSet<String>();


        File rewardsFile = Controller.kasasaFile;
        BufferedReader rewardsBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(rewardsFile), "utf-8"));


        File billPayFile = Controller.billPayFile;
        BufferedReader billPayBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(billPayFile), "utf-8"));


        // Workaround for ByteOrderMarker that is present in files on Windows' environmentsKnown bug in Java with regards to reading files
        bomSkip(rewardsBR);
        scanKasasa(rewardsBR, rewardsAccountsList);
        scanBillPay(billPayBR, billPayAccountsList);

        Set<String> intersection = intersectionOfSets(rewardsAccountsList, billPayAccountsList);

        printOutFile(intersection);
    }
```

It seems as though my fxml document is not being loaded properly. Any idea on what would cause this? Would it be anything to do with a manifest or resource file?

Comment: You should provide us some code and what exceptions you have encountered if any.

Comment: Code was added. No exceptions are had unless the user closes the interface without selecting files, which should not cause the lack of interface problem.

Comment: More than likely your FXML is not being included in your jar file and isn't loaded.

Comment: Run the jar file from the command line to verify for certain there are no exceptions (if you haven't already). Check the contents of the jar and make sure the FXML file is present (which I think it must be, since you wouldn't see the window otherwise), and make sure it is the most up-to-date version (try cleaning and rebuilding the project and jar file).

Comment: Any idea on how I would go about fixing that? The fxml file is showing in the source and bin folders of the project.

Comment: Did you check the jar file? (`jar -tf path/to/jarfile.jar`)

Comment: I'm getting 'jar' is not recognized as a command error when typing that into cmd. java -version is working though. I have ran the file from the command line to verify no exceptions (except for when the interface is closed without a file being selected which I am aware of).

Comment: So specify the full path to the jar executable (same location as the JDK java executable). (Or you can copy the jar file and rename the copy as a zip file, then unzip it... but that is kind of extreme)